# Property access on a subclass of HashMap

Tags: groovy

I have the following class that is a subclass of `HashMap` and has getters and setters for some entries in the map.

**Please note:** This class is coming from a framework I use, so I cannot modify it

```
class Mapish extends HashMap {
  static final PROPERTY_KEY = 'PROP'

  def getProperty() {
    get(PROPERTY_KEY)
  }

  def setProperty(def value) {
    put(PROPERTY_KEY, value)
  }
}
```

Is it possible to turn off the Groovy's Map property notation for this class, so that the property access will invoke the getter? In other words to make the following will pass?

```
def m = new Mapish()
m.setProperty('value')

assert m.property == 'value' // same as m.getProperty()
```

and the following would throw groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException

```
m.PROP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long debugging session I've found that `MetaClassImpl` has a property called `isMap`. In case the given class is assignable to `Map` this is `true`. This variable makes the class have groovy Map syntax sugar, so if set to `false` the class instances won't behave as Maps. The only catch is that the field is `final`, so reflection is needed to set it to `false`

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier

class Mapish extends HashMap {
  static final PROPERTY_KEY = 'PROP'

  def getProperty() {
    get(PROPERTY_KEY)
  }

  def setProperty(def value) {
    put(PROPERTY_KEY, value)
  }

}

// this method does basically this: c.metaClass.delegate.@isMap = false
// but since isMap is final the assignment throws exception
def unmapify(Class c) {
  def meta = c.metaClass.delegate
  def isMapField = meta.class.getDeclaredField("isMap")
  def modifiersField = Field.getDeclaredField("modifiers")
  modifiersField.accessible = true
  modifiersField.setInt(isMapField, isMapField.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL)

  isMapField.accessible = true
  isMapField.set(meta, false)
}

unmapify(Mapish)

def m = new Mapish()
m.setProperty('value')

assert m.property == 'value'

try {
  m.PROP
  assert false
} catch (ignore) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe [meta-programming](http://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html) can help here.

Consider the following:

```
// original

class Mapish extends HashMap {
    static final PROPERTY_KEY = 'PROP'

    def getProperty() {
        get(PROPERTY_KEY)
    }

    def setProperty(def value) {
        put(PROPERTY_KEY, value)
    }
}

// meta-programming augmentation

Mapish.metaClass.getProperty { String arg ->
    if (arg == "property") {
        delegate.getProperty()
    } else {
        throw new MissingPropertyException("illegal property: " + arg)
    }
}

// test

def m = new Mapish()

m.setProperty("foo")
assert "foo" == m.property

try {
    m.PROP
    throw IllegalStateException("should not get here")
} catch (MissingPropertyException ex) {
    // println "caught exception as expected"
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but my problem is that if lets say the given class has 20 properties I have to add an `if` for each of them which I'd like to avoid. I've found a way to hack the `MetaClassImpl` so groovy does not treat the class as a `Map`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way to make Maps not behave as Maps in Groovy. Perhaps you should consider not extending `HashMap` at all. Something like this would give you the behavior you are looking for:

```
class Mapish {
  static final PROPERTY_KEY = 'PROP'
  private map = [:]
  private getMap() { throw new groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException() }
  private void setMap(def map) { throw new groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException() }

  def getProperty() {
    map[PROPERTY_KEY]
  }

  def setProperty(def value) {
    map[PROPERTY_KEY] = value
  }
}
```

Then I would expect your code samples to behave exactly as you wish.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but my issue is that I cannot modify the class as it is coming from a library that the application is using

Comment: Ahh, you might want to add that information to your question statement too. Never mind, just saw it.

Comment: It is already stated in the beginning, but I'll edit the question to make it more visible

Comment: No need, you're right. I misread the clearly stated question.